# Are sheaves a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. Can the assignment $U\in\mathrm{Open}(X)\mapsto \{\text{sheaves on $U$}\}$ be made into a sheaf, rigorously?

There is some hint in [Kedlaya's course notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-726-algebraic-geometry-spring-2009/f20e0e9cada2de9f19ed6718a94371f5_MIT18_726s09_lec03_sheaves.pdf) in which it says "a sheaf of sheaves is a sheaf" (see the corollary there).

Also, in MacLane and Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* it says in chapter II, section 1:

> In fact, since the notion of a sheaf is "local", this functor is itself almost a sheaf.

I wonder: why "almost"?

Comment: It can be made into a 2-sheaf (also known as a stack), which is a 2-categorical generalisation of a sheaf. A sheaf is a certain functor $Open(X)^{op} \to C$, where $C$ is a 1-category, satisfying a certain limit condition. A stack is a functor $Open(X)^{op} \to D$, where $D$ is a 2-category, satisfying a more complicated condition. In this case, $D$ is the category of categories and $C$ is the category of sets.

Comment: @MarkSaving Can it be made into a 1-sheaf too? If not, why not?

Comment: It cannot be made into a 1-sheaf. The reason, roughly speaking, is automorphisms.

Comment: Thank you very much, MarkSaving and ZhenLin!

Comment: @ZhenLin: I wouldn't be so categorical.  Recall that the category of simplicial sheaves is Quillen equivalent to the category of simplicial presheaves, when both are equipped with the local model structure.  The left Quillen equivalence is given by the degreewise sheafification functor.  Although I haven't checked the details, it is not inconceivable that the model categories of presheaves of categories and sheaves of categories are Quillen equivalent, when both are equipped with the local model structure.  This would answer OP's question in the affirmative.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is technically possible to have a gadget that is simultaneously a sheaf and a stack… but it seems difficult and at any rate I doubt the assignment under discussion would be such a gadget.

Comment: The usual result you would use to glue sheaves would be: suppose $U_i$ cover $X$, and on each $U_i$ you have a sheaf $\mathscr{F}_i$, along with transition maps $\rho_{ij} : \mathscr{F}_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathscr{F}_j |_{U_i \cap U_j}$ satisfying $\rho_{ii} = \operatorname{id}$ and $\rho_{ik} |_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} = \rho_{jk} |_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} \circ \rho_{ij} |_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k}$.  Then there is a gluing sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, unique up to unique isomorphism, along with maps $f_i : \mathscr{F}|_{U_i} \to \mathscr{F}_i$, such that...

Comment: $\rho_{ij} \circ f_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j |_{U_i \cap U_j}$.

Answer (score 1):

To make it rigorous, we need the correct interpretation of the "set" $\{\text{sheaves on } U\}$.

First of all, we can't consider sheaves up to isomorphism. If we would do this, then the assignment wouldn't be a sheaf, because sheaves that are locally isomorphic are not necessarily isomorphic.

A second idea is to consider sheaves up to equality, where two sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are defined to be equal if $\mathcal{F}(U)=\mathcal{G}(U)$ for every open set $U \subseteq X$. In this way, the assignment $U \mapsto \{\text{sheaves on }U\}$ is still not a sheaf. Gluing sheaves that are locally equal is not a problem (use the cocycle condition), however the gluing is only unique up to isomorphism, not up to equality.

The "correct" approach is to use étale spaces over $X$. The category of étale spaces over $X$ is equivalent to the category of sheaves on $X$, but the notion of equality is different. Here the natural notion of equality is to say that two étale spaces $f : Y \to X$ and $f' : Y' \to X$ are equal if $Y=Y'$ and $f=f'$. In this setting, suppose that you have an open covering $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ and étale spaces $f_i : Y_i \to U_i$ for all $i \in I$, then there is a unique étale space $f : Y \to X$ restricting to this, namely $Y = \bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i$ with $f$ the unique function restricting to each $f_i$ on $Y_i$. So the assignment
$$U \mapsto \{ \text{étale spaces over }U\}$$
forms a sheaf.

There are two technical issues that I didn't mention yet. First, there are size issues: there are too many sheaves (even up to isomorphism) to get a set, so you will get a proper class instead, or a set in a higher universe. So even if you get a sheaf, it will be a sheaf of proper classes, not a sheaf of sets. A second issue is that the second and third approach both use notions of "equality" based on equality of sets. This is not a problem if you work with a material set theory like ZF or ZFC, but it is an issue if you work with a structural set theory like ETCS.